# Where to get list of known repositories like @bazel_tools, @rules_jvm_external etc?

Tags: bazel

Sometimes I see extensions loading from the internet or built-in ones.
Canonical example:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
```

However, I cannot distinguish local repo and known repo by looking at the `load` expression.

How can I check the source (location) of any repo which I see in my WORKSPACE/BUILD files?

Comment: I ran `bazel query --output=build //external:bazel_tools`
And then using google reverse-mapped it to :
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/tools/build_defs/repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bazel query --output=build //external:repo_name` works just fine.

Comment: No, it actually doesn't work fine.  
  `bazel query --output=build //external:bazel_tools`
just displays the temp file directory where bazel_tools was downloaded on my machine.  I would prefer to know where it came from on the internet!

Answer (score 0):

If the Bazel label is sufficient as a source, you might try fetching repo roots with BUILD files with `bazel query 'buildfiles(//...)'`.

Otherwise, you could run `bazel clean --expunge` and run a build with `--experimental_execution_log_file=<FILENAME>`. This creates a protobuf based log of the actions by Bazel. In there, all internet repos are downloaded anew because of `clean --expunge`.

Check https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/tools/execlog for a parser.

It is super inconvenient that this information is not available another way - afaik. I really hope someone swings by and corrects me, but this way you at least know the available sources you can correlate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Bazel, but as far as I understand:

- Copy the name of the repo. E.g. `io_bazel_rules_docker`
- Search it through the codebase
- Look at how it's being loaded

E.g. if you see

```
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_docker",
    ...
)
http_file(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_docker",
    ...
)
```

And you can conclude where it's coming from.